# Angular bootstrap ui tabs ngMessage doesn't work in the first tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-messages

I bumped into a strange behaviour of ngMessage

into an angular ui bootstrap tabs the validation

doesn't work in the first tab

the code

**js**

```
angular
        .module('app', ['ngMessages','ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
        function MainCtrl() {}
```

**html**

```
<body class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
        <uib-tabset active="0" justified="true">
            <uib-tab index="0">
                <uib-tab-heading>
                  <ul class="header">
                    <li class="title">title 1</li>
                    <li class="description">Descr 1</li>
                  </ul>
                </uib-tab-heading>
                <div class="tab-pane-general">
                   <form name="form" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.location.$touched && form.location.$invalid }">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="main.location"
                                ng-minlength="5"
                                ng-maxlength="10"
                                required>
                            <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.location.$error" ng-show="form.location.$touched">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
                                    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
                                    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>         
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="1">
                <uib-tab-heading>
                  <ul class="header">
                    <li class="title">title 2</li>
                    <li class="description">Descr 2</li>
                  </ul>
                </uib-tab-heading>
                <div class="tab-pane-general">
                    <form name="form" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.location.$touched && form.location.$invalid }">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="main.location"
                                ng-minlength="5"
                                ng-maxlength="10"
                                required>
                            <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.location.$error" ng-show="form.location.$touched">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
                                    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
                                    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>         
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/tab-pane-general -->
            </uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="2">
                <uib-tab-heading>
                  <ul class="header">
                    <li class="title">title 3</li>
                    <li class="description">Descr 3</li>
                  </ul>
                </uib-tab-heading>
                <div class="tab-pane-general">
                    TAB THREE
                </div><!--/tab-pane-general -->
            </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/whisher/pen/QEyyzz

Is it a bug ?

Any idea ?

### UPDATE

I worked it out in the real app I've set an input with the same name ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `<form>` has same names. So if You change first to `name1` and second to `name2` all will work fine.

You can read more about angular form validation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Yes, but it is not correct to use same names for forms in angular. The error occurred because of same names.

Comment: if you get rid of the validation in the second tab the first one doesn't work

Comment: Sorry you agree changing the form name it works but still doesn't work in the real app :(

Comment: I worked it out in the real app I've set an input with the same name ^^ thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need two form tags? As every form tag has it own validation. So if you want 1 validation for whole tab control then you will need to put just one form tag